# Is the Least Squares system Lipschitz?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, regression, least-squares

I wanted to show that least squares is Lipschitz. Consider

$$ L(w) = \| Xw -y \|^2$$

its K-Lipschitz if:

$$ \| L(b) - L(a) \|^2 \leq K\| b- a \|^2$$

so I did:

$$ L(b) - L(a) = b^T X^T X b - a^T X^T X a - 2 y^T X b + 2 y^T X a$$

$$ = b^T X^T X b - a^T X^T X a - 2 y^T X (b-a) $$

now I want to factor a $b-a$ from $b^T X^T X b - a^T X^T X a$ but I didn't know how. Any ideas?

When thing are only numbers i.e. 1D its easy cuz we get $b^2 - a^2$:

$$ L(b) - L(a) = | (xb-y)^2 - (xa-y)^2 |$$
$$ =  |x^2b^2 - x^2 a^2 + 2xby - 2xay | = | x^2 (b+a)(b-a) + 2xy(b-a)|$$
$$ = | x^2 (b+a)+ 2xy||b-a|$$

which shows its Lipschitz... but had difficulty generalizing this regression problem...it's obvious to me that its some property of linear algebra that I don't know or know how to conjure up...

Comment: Your work in 1D does not show it's Lipschitz because $|x^2 (b+a) + 2xy|$ still depends on $a, b$. The factor in front of $|b - a|$ should be independent of $a, b$.

Comment: @VHarisop so quadratics aren't LIpschitz? So what is Lipschitz?

Comment: No, quadratics aren't Lipschitz. Norms, inner products, and anything that doesn't change "abruptly" as you change $x$ is Lipschitz. A function whose value changes some order of magnitude greater than the change in $x$ will not be Lipschitz, as is the case for a quadratic.

Comment: @VHarisop so inner products and norms aren't Lipschitz?

Comment: Inner products and norms **are** Lipschitz, that is precisely what I wrote.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't true. For simplicity consider the case where $X$ is a scalar equal to $1$ and $y=0$. Then $(L(a)-L(b))^2=(a^2 - b^2 )^2=(a+b)^2(a-b)^2$. So for any $K$ if $(a+b)^2>K$ then $(L(a)-L(b))^2>K(a-b)^2$.

However, if you impose that $|a|$ and $|b|$ are bounded then you're fine. In that case suppose that we impose $||a||^2,||b||^2\leq L$ for some scalar $L$. Now, you can easily verify that (just use the associativity of matrix multiplication): $ a^T X^T Xa - b^T X^T Xb = (a-b)^T X^T Xb +b^T X^T X(a-b) + (a-b)^T X^T X (a-b) $ And so applying the triangle inequality you get:

$||L(a)-L(b)||^2\leq (2||b||^2||X^T X||^2+2||y^T X||^2+||a-b||^2 ||X^T X||^2)||a-b||^2$

Where the norm is the operator norm if the argument is a matrix. And so using the boundedness of $||a||^2$ and $||b||^2$ you get:

$||L(a)-L(b)||^2\leq (4L||X^T X||^2+2||y^T X||^2)||a-b||^2$

And so you can set $K=(4L||X^T X||^2+2||y^T X||^2)$

Comment: from ur first simple example in 1D. Is the this squared system only Lipschitz if $a+b \leq 1$? I'm having a hard interpreting intuitively what this means...

Comment: In the first example it's Lipschitz if and only if $(a+b)^2\leq C$ for some constant $C$ in which case the Lipschitz constant $K$ is at most $C$. If for some constant $c$, $|a|\leq c$ and $|b|\leq c$ then we must have $(a+b)^2\leq 4c^2$ and so we can set $K=4c^2$

Comment: $K = |x^2(b+a)+2xy|$ but with ur values it gives $K=|a+b|$. I would have thought we needed $(a+b)^2 < |a+b|$ to be satisfied which means  $(a+b) \leq 1 $...is that correct?

Comment: $K$ can't depend on $a$ or $b$, it is a constant.

Comment: ah I see so we need to restrict the interval for it to become a constant. Thanks! In my question a quadratic bowl can just be restricted to some Radius around its center or something, so in practice for this problem the Lipschitz constant should be easy to find no?

Comment: is the restriction to an interval a technical detail or is there a fundamental issue with quadratics (and norm like functions)?

Comment: It's a fundamental issue. In the simple case of a function of a scalar $f(\cdot )$ and the function is everywhere differentiable then it is Lipschitz on some interval if and only if the derivative is bounded. The derivative of say $x^2$ is $2x$ and so if $x$ is unbounded (i.e. the interval is the whole real line) then clearly you also can't upper-bound $2x$.

Comment: As an example of a function that is Lipschitz even when the interval is unbounded consider $sine(x)$ the derivative of that is $cosine(x)$ which is bounded above by $1$ and below by $-1$ and so it is Lipschitz even if $x$ is unbounded.